# installing spacemacs without disturbing existing emacs

Tags: spacemacs

I have been using `emacs` for a while, and i recently installed `zsh` and i wanted to give a try with `spacemacs`. I want to try `spacemacs` without disturbing existing `emacs`.

I followed the instruction as mentioned [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs#modify-home-environment-variable).

- created a dir `~/spacemacs`
- `git clone https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs.git ~/spacemacs/.emacs.d`
- `HOME=~/spacemacs emacs`

I did the first two steps. But im not sure to do the last step `HOME=~/spacemacs emacs`, because i want things to be as follows. when i give `emacs`, my default `emacs` should open, and when i give `semacs` i want to open `spacemacs`.

So far, i have modified my `.zshrc` file in such a way that, when i give the command `emacs` it fires up `emacs`, so i have an alias like such `alias emacs='emacs -nw'`.

And i want to give `semacs`(alias for `spacemacs`) open `spacemacs`, so that i can open `emacs` any time i wanted to, if im not comfortable with `spacemacs`. Now what should be the 3rd step as and what should be my alias look like.

Comment: Closely related: [Running spacemacs alongside regular emacs: how to keep a separate .emacs.d](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19936/running-spacemacs-alongside-regular-emacs-how-to-keep-a-separate-emacs-d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, what you want to do is set up an alias. The third command, `HOME=~/spacemacs emacs`, will launch emacs using the Spacemacs configuration and layers. So, all you should need to do is put

```
alias semacs='HOME=~/spacemacs emacs'
```

in your `.zshrc` file, and restart the shell.

As a caveat, I am not very familiar with zsh, but am reasonably experienced with bash. <del>I assume simple aliases like this should work the same.</del>

---

**EDIT:** I was unable to personally get the alias working in zsh. However, I was able to do it using a shell function (based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7966)):

```
semacs() {
  HOME=~/spacemacs emacs $@
}
```

Comment: what does the 3rd step means if i directly give them in the terminal as said in the link

Comment: @arvindh The third step means "launch emacs using the spacemacs configuration." Also, have you restarted your shell after modifying .zshrc? The easiest way to do this is just to run the zsh command again.

Comment: thanks for the information on restarting zsh. Now after restarting zsh when i give `semacs` its opening basic gnu `emacs`. and it does not start `spacemacs`

Comment: You are right—I should have tried this before posting it. My zsh inexperience is showing. I have updated the answer with a shell function that you can use instead of the alias. This time I actually tried it first ;-) Sorry for the runaround.

Comment: Thanks @Violet. It worked. And i have to mention one more thing for someone who end up with same thing. Previously i had emacs 24.3 as default and spacemacs works with 24.4 above. So i had to install recent version and change the line as `{HOME=~/spacemacs emacs-25.1 $@}` (your version number over there, i installed 25.1 so i had to change it to 25.1)

Comment: It's almost always better to use a script than a shell function or alias.  Shell functions and aliases only work from within the shell they're defined in, but scripts can be called from anywhere.